# Correct the sentence

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

I'm trying to say: "It's not true. You are sitting the fourth from the right side"

那不是真的。 你坐在第四个右边。

Is it correct?

Comment: alternative suggestion: 那不是真的。你坐右边第四座位

Answer (score 1):

As @user6065 suggested in the comment:

`你坐在第四个右边` is weird in its word order.

By your context， I think you should say `你坐在右起第四个（座位）` or `你的座位是从右数第四个`.

Comment: Let's imagine a photo. There are a lot of people. And one said: it's hard to find me. So I'm trying to say that "It's not true [I see you]. You are the fourth person from the right".

Comment: or: "you are sitting the fourth from the right."

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

没有啊，你就是右边第四个人

it's not (hard) at all, you're (right here -) the 4th person from the right